# user press the key "0" in jogl how can I do it?

Tags: input, jogl

I want to show and hide an implemented object if a user press the key "0" in jogl how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a key listener into the focused component exactly as you would do with any Java software using AWT and Swing. If you use NEWT, you'll have to use a key listener too anyway.

Then implement the method keyReleased(KeyEvent), modify the value of a boolean field when 0 is released and look at this value in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable) to determine whether to show or hide your object.